# How to get additional information via bing search api

Tags: api, bing, web-search

I use Bing Web Search API. Everything works, but i can't to get the information under the URL. For example, when we search the query "site:linkedin.com somebody", we get some informations under the link, like "x connections". 
Is there anyway to get these informations via the API?